# WiFi range extender drops connection after a day. Rebooting main router fixes it

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I have an issue which I can't seem to get to the bottom of. My main router works great, but to increase the range I recently added a WiFi range extender.

The range extender was easy to set up, and worked immediately. I ended up with 2 separate access points (AP1 which is my main router, and AP2 which is the range extender). From any devices, I connect to either AP1 or AP2 SSID.

After between 12-24 hours however, AP2 is still visible, but I cannot connect to it from any device. The connection just fails.

Rebooting the range extender does not help. It's not until I reboot AP1 (main router) that AP2 starts working again. AP1 will be fully functional the whole time though.

I have tried fixing the router's WiFi channel in the router so that it doesn't change, and I have tried limiting it to just 20MHz mode. Neither of those settings seem to help.

Is there anything else I could try?

If it helps, I am using a BT HomeHub 3, and a Belkin D300 Range Extender.

Comment: Wifi extenders are **horrible**. It's far worth your time and money to install network cabling from your network rack to the second AP location and then install a real access point there in place of the extender.

Answer (score 0):

An wifi extender is actually another connections, what happens is when you go from one coverage area to another you device switches connections from devices very quickly, so you will not be connected on both at the same time, your wifi card will not let that happen.
You could have set the connection permission timer on the extender or router.
Is it and specific time it happens, say like at 8pm? Could be heavy interference in that specific period in this case. You could measure it with a tool like Wifi Analyzer for Android or Acrylic WiFi Free for Windows.
Could be also an defective product, but I don't think that's the case.